# SQLite: Query to get common attributes

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

i have two tables like 
**product**:
id,code,slug etc
and **attribute**:
id, product_id(FK to **product**), name,value

I want to select all common attribute related to a product code
Eg:

```
Table: product
id -  code
1  -  C1
2  -  C1
3  -  C1

Table: attribute
id - product_id  - name  - value
1  - 1     -       W   -   10
2  - 1     -       H   -   12


3 -  2     -       W   -   10
4 -  2     -       H   -   2
5 -  2     -       T   -   12


6 -  3     -       W   -   10
...
```

How can i get the **attribute** rows that corresponds to product code

For Eg: the product code C1. The common attributes(name, value) of product code C1 is
  **name=W  and value=10** because those have same name and values

also it should return null if product id 3 is not present in attribute table.

Comment: The description is unclear. Show the desired output for your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT product.code,
       attribute.name,
       attribute.value
FROM product
JOIN attribute ON product.id = attribute.product_id
GROUP BY product.code,
         attribute.name,
         attribute.value
HAVING count(*) = (SELECT count(*)
                   FROM product AS p2
                   WHERE p2.code = product.code)
```

Comment: This is working. one problem is there is products that dont have an attribute, at that time it results mull row. how can we limit the result to a particular product_code(eg: for product code 'C1').

Comment: Fixed; this shouldn't have been an outer join.